# Can not open an url and print the page in Chrome

Tags: javascript

On Chrome (I only tried this so far) I can open an empty window, write a line and automatically print the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openWin()
  {
    var win = window.open('','','width=600,height=600');
    win.document.write("Write a line here!");
    win.document.close();
    win.focus();
    setTimeout( function () {
      win.print();
      win.close();
    }, 1000 );
  }
</script>
...
<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />
```

But I can't open an URL and automatically print the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openWin()
  {
    var win = window.open('http://google.it','','width=600,height=600');
    win.document.close();
    win.focus();
    setTimeout( function () {
      win.print();
      win.close();
    }, 1000 );
  }
</script>
...
<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />
```

Is this possible? Has Chrome some limitations?

1. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Xc9/3479/
2. Not-working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Xc9/3484/

Comment: Do you want to print google only, or some local page?

Comment: Google page was just an example, I'd like to print any page